# Adding and trimming spaces before and after separator

Tags: excel, excel-formula, separator, excel-2019

If string contain text with one single special character (separator),

How to ad a space after point before separator and trim any space after separator?

**Exemple string:**

- *.Dolo.rum ipsum primos@ ar.deo*
- *J.ust. simple text@ h er.e*
- *Another fr.e.e @. exe mpl e*

**Expect result:**

- *. Dolo. rum ipsum primos@ar.deo*
- *J. ust. simple text@her.e*
- *Another fr. e. e @.exemple*

Comment: Check out substitute(). And trim(). Often one can find useful functions by looking through the list of functions and reading the explanations given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since an accepted answer can't be deleted hence sharing the solution as mentioned in the first comment,

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND("@",A1)),".",". ")&SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("@",A1)+1,LEN(A1))," ","")
```